# sticky sidebar switching from position

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am making a sticky sidebar that 'sticks' to the top of the page when the user scrolls past it. However, the sidebar does not work as it should, it keeps switching back and forth between static and fixed positioning as the user scrolls.

```
$(document).scroll(function () {
        var docScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
        var stickyListOffset = $(".sticky-list").offset().top;
        if(docScroll > stickyListOffset){ 
          $(".sticky-list").css({
             'position' : 'fixed',
             'top' : '0px',
             'width' : '100%'
          }); 
        } else {
          $(".sticky-list").css({
             'position' : 'static'
          })
        }
    });
```

CSS:

```
.sticky-list {
    background:#7C9ED9;
    padding:1em;
    list-style:none;
    font-family:Domine, serif;
}
.sticky-list #indicator {
    font-size:.8em;
    color:#fff;
    font-style:italic;
    font-family:Bitter, serif;
}
.sticky-list #indicator:after {
    width:100%;
    content:"";
    display:block;
    background:#fff;
    height:2px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="jump-list" class="sticky-list">
    <span id="indicator">Jump To...</span>
    <li><a href="#open-console">Opening the Console</a></li>
    <li><a href="#writing-to-console">Writing to the Console</a></li>
</ul>
```

However, the jump bar flickers between static and fixed positioning, instead of how it should. Why is this not working?
[Page](http://tricksfortheweb.net46.net/tutorials/using-the-console)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set the position to fixed, the `offset().top` of the sticky-list changes to `$(this).scrollTop + 10`, because of the `"top: 10"` style of your sticky-list.
Change

```
if(docScroll > stickyListOffset){
```

to

```
if(docScroll + 10 >= stickyListOffset){
```

and it should work

Comment: No, it is still flickering.

Answer (score 0):

the `.offset().top` value is changing while you scroll.that's why it's flickering. you need to calculate `.offset().top` BEFORE the `scroll function`

i suggest you don't use css inside jQuery because it adds inline css and that's not really a good thing. instead add a class when sticky and style that class in css. this would be the 'cleanest` way to do this.

also calculate `.outherHeight() + .offset().top` if you want the list to become sticky AFTER you get past it.

`.outherHeight()` because the `ul` has a `padding:1em` and just using `.height()` doesn't take into account the padding .

i calculated when the list should be sticky with some variables to be more clear

see snippet

```js
 var stickyHeight = $(".sticky-list").outerHeight(),
     stickyListOffset = $(".sticky-list").offset().top,
     whenToSticky = stickyHeight + stickyListOffset
$(document).scroll(function () {
        var docScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
       
        if(docScroll > whenToSticky ){ 
          $(".sticky-list").addClass("sticky")
        } else {
          $(".sticky-list").removeClass("sticky")
        }
    });
```

```css
.sticky-list {
    background:#7C9ED9;
    padding:1em;
    list-style:none;
    font-family:Domine, serif;
}
.sticky-list #indicator {
    font-size:.8em;
    color:#fff;
    font-style:italic;
    font-family:Bitter, serif;
}
.sticky-list #indicator:after {
    width:100%;
    content:"";
    display:block;
    background:#fff;
    height:2px;
}
.content {
  height:800px;
  background:red;
}

.sticky-list.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top : 0px;
  width : 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="jump-list" class="sticky-list">
    <span id="indicator">Jump To...</span>
    <li><a href="#open-console">Opening the Console</a></li>
    <li><a href="#writing-to-console">Writing to the Console</a></li>
</ul> 
<div class="content">

</div>
```

let me know if it helps